# OAuth with Spotify unable to get refresh token using curl

Tags: php, curl, oauth, spotify

I've been creating my own Spotify API for a project. I've followed the Web API tutorial and I still can not get an authorization for a refresh token.

This request is made immediately after I get my first authorization successfully.

Can anyone spot an issue with my code?

```
//Request for refresh token
$url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";
$fieldString = "";
$fields = array(
    "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
    "code" => $_GET['code'],
    "redirect_uri" => $spotify->getRedirectURI()
    //"client_id" => $spotify->getClientID(),
    //"client_secret" => $spotify->getClientSecret()
);
$headers = array(
    "Accept: application/json",
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($spotify->getClientID().":".$spotify->getClientSecret())
);

echo http_build_query($fields)."<br/>";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($fields));

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump(json_decode($response));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason I was receiving a bad response is because I needed:

```
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

After I inserted that line, I was able to acquire my tokens. Hopefully this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The correct option to set header is `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` and unfortunately you are using `CURLOPT_HEADER`. That's why your authorization header is not set with curl request.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

Comment: I'm still getting null as the response

Comment: You can run the code with verbose mode enable and see the curl is sending as exactly what you are trying to send or not. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);`

Comment: I still only receive a 'null'. Nothing else was displayed.